# Find an expression for z as a function of w in terms of the complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find an expression for z as a function of w in terms of the complex logarithm,
where
$w = f(z) := 2 \exp(z) + \exp(2z)$
and use it to find all values of z for which $f(z) = 3$

I'm having problems with this question I keep getting $\log(w)=z^2+2z$ using log laws but then I am stuck how would you approach this? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Write $y=exp(z)$ to get $w=2y+y^2$. Solve quadratic for y, then easy to get z in terms of w.

Comment: It would be good to use a backslash before an exp, log or trig function. This way you properly display the functions. I edited your post to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=\exp(z)$, so the equation is

$$x^2+ 2x - w = 0 \to x_{\pm} = -1 \pm \sqrt{1+w}\to z_{\pm} = \ln[-1\pm \sqrt{(1+w)} ]$$